# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Current transaction is not in progress

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hi I'm trying to Process some Employees objects and Persist in Database. The Service layer may get an exception from DAO layer. But I still need to process other employee records.

Please look  the below Class Example. Here Class A.processEmployees() calls other class EmpHandler which calls DAO. Even if some exception came for an employee, I need other Employees to be processed and Persisted in Database. However, I'm getting Exception as **org.hibernate.HibernateException: Current transaction is not in progress**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
Class A
{

 public void processEmployees(List<Employee> empList)
 {
   for (Employee emp : empList) 
     new EmpHandler().processEmployee(emp);
 }

}
```

Comment: Does transaction started and active into A#processEmployees? Does Exception throw by EmpHandler#processEmployee?

Comment: @samolisov that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create EmpHandler by call the `new` method. Therefore that's methods do not handle by Spring Framework and some other containers. You do not should create the `EmpHandler` object by yourself. Spring Framework should create this object.

You can do following:

```
Class A
{

    private IEmpHandler handler;

    public void setEmpHandler(IEmpHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void processEmployees(List<Employee> empList)
    {
        for (Employee emp : empList) 
            handler.processEmployee(emp);
    }
}

class EmpHandler implements IEmpHandler {
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void processEmployee(...) {
    }
}
```

In your context.xml:

```
<bean id="handler" class="...EmpHandler"/>

<bean id="a" class = "...A">
    <property name="handler" ref="handler"/>
</bean>
```